# The maximum number of edges in an even-cycle-free graph with $n$ vertices

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

**Problem**
Given any positive integer $n$, what is the maximum number of edges in an even-cycle-free graph with $n$ vertices?

Is the above problem an unsolved problem in extremal graph theory? Are there any results about this problem?

Comment: Tony's argument below should answer your question. It's also worth mentioning that the problem of maximizing the number of edges in a graph forbidding an even cycle of fixed length is well studied (see, e.g., the Bondy-Simonovits Theorem).

Comment: This problem can be found in L. Lovasz, Combinatorial Problems and Exercises, 10.1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is $\lfloor \frac{3}{2}(n-1)\rfloor$.  First note that if $G$ is $2$-connected and even-cycle-free, then $G$ must just be an odd cycle.  To see this, consider an [ear-decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ear_decomposition) of $G$.  If $G$ is not just a cycle, then $G$ contains a cycle and an ear. However, by parity considerations, a cycle and an ear always contains an even cycle.

Now let $G$ be an arbitrary even-cycle-free graph and consider its [block-cut-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component) $T$.  By the previous remark, each block of $G$ is an odd cycle or just an edge.  To maximize the number of edges, each block of $G$ should be a triangle.  Thus, the maximum number of edges is attained by a 'tree of $k$ triangles.' This graph has $3k$ edges and $2k+1$ vertices. For $n$ even (say $n=2k+2$), the maximum is attained when $T$ has exactly $k$ blocks which are triangles and exactly one block which is an edge.  This is a complete characterization of the extremal examples.